# How does WM_KEYDOWN process different keys?

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl, game-engine

This is a rather unusual question, but I need some explanation on exactly how Win32 handles different keydown events.

`WM_KEYDOWN` is used when you want to receive long presses, e.g. if you're in a game, and you want to move forward, you press UP arrow key, or 'W' key, and the character in the game moves on.
You do not have to press the keys multiple times, because of `WM_KEYDOWN`.

I have a 3D OpenGL application, based on win32, in which I am using both 'W-A-S-D' and `arrow key` to move around in the 3D world. They both work exactly how they're supposed to work.

Being said that, when I am in the 3D world, I can sense there is a subtle difference between the way Win32 handles `WASD` and arrow keys.

```
    case UP_k: 
    f_zPosition-=CAM_MOVEMENT_SPEED; 
     break;
```

The same code is also used for `case 'W':`.

But in the game, for some reason the movement done by arrow keys is much smoother than the movement of `WASD` keys.

1. How does Win32 handles these events internally?
2. How can I make
   the movement by `WASD` smooth like arrow keys.

I wonder if anyone has ever noticed this in Win32, here is my event loop code, as per requested in the comments.

```
do
{
    window.displayGL();
    PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE);
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage (&msg);

}while(msg.message != WM_QUIT);
```

Comment: Can you post the code of your event loop? My guess is it has something to do with the TranslateMessage function.

Comment: There is no difference that I am aware of. Unless, of course, you have the Alt/Meta/etc. key down at the same time; then the arrow keys behave a little differently. Though, if you have Alt down, there is a different Window Message you have to handle altogether.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman, I am not using Alt at the moment. Its simple arrow keys and WASD. jspurim, I have added the event loop.

Comment: Oh, hmm. You are actually doing something here that I would suggest you avoid: relying on ***autorepeat*** to send `WM_KEYDOWN` messages over and over while you hold the key down. I would *always* ignore a `WM_KEYDOWN` event with `lParam` bit 30 set to **1**, that indicates a repeated key message. Instead of handling movement when the user presses a button, set a state when the key is initially pressed down and then reset it when it is released. When it comes time to periodically handle movement, check the state that was set, rather than responding only to auto-repeat generated messages.

Comment: Ok, that could work, I already have the states for ctrl in place, I can do something like that. That should definitely make the movement faster. 

But I am still wondering how does arrow keys behave differently than character keys.

Comment: @2am I think that the "edit" keys (e.g. backspace, arrows, tab, ...) repeat quicker than alphanumeric. To make changing the input caret position and such more responsive in traditional text-input scenarios.

Comment: Did you try the `TranslateMessage` commenting out I suggested? Did It have any effect?

Comment: @jspurim, Yes, you were right, after commenting out TranslateMessage the issue was resolved. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A normal message proccesing loop on a win32 applications calls two functions:

```
TranslateMessage(&msg);
DispatchMessage(&msg);
```

The first function, `TranslateMessage` looks at virtual key messages (that is `WM_KEYDOWN` messages for example) and then adds character messages to the message queue if the pressed key corresponds to a character key. If you keep the `'W'` key pressed, a lot of `WM_KEYDOWN` are generated because of the autorepeat feature. The same goes for the arrow keys, but in the case of the `'W`', for every `WM_KEYDOWN` a `WM_CHAR` is also generated, which your application will have to process.

Even if your application just looks at the `WM_CHAR` and discards them, the resulting delay may be noticeable, especially because you move the camera each time you process a `WM_KEYDOWN`

For more info check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg153546(v=vs.85).aspx).

**The solution:**

You should make your movement speed independent of the speed at which you process your input. There are two main ways to do that:

- **Fixed framerate:** Update your screen a fixed number of times per second. On each update move the camera/player the same distance.
- **Timed frames** Update your screen as many times as you can, but measure the time between iterations. When you move, multiply the movement speed by the time since last update.

In both cases, **don't move your character when you process the input.** Instead, when you get a `WM_KEYDOWN` set a boolean `playerIsMoving` to `true`, and reset it to `false` when you get a `WM_KEYUP`. Then apply the movement when you generate your next frame only if the variable is in `true`.

**[UPDATE]**

After seeing your main loop:
Try modifying it like this:

**Modification 1**: Comment out `TranslateMessage`. You don't need it unless you want to have textboxes and the like in your app.

**Modification 2**: Add a separate function to update world state.

```
do
{
    UpdateWorld()
    window.displayGL();
    PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE);
    //TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage (&msg);

}while(msg.message != WM_QUIT); 

// I won't define exactly all of this, you can get an idea 
// what I'm doing by the names. playerIsMoving should be set
// and reset in the `WindowProcedure` when processing 'WM_KEYDOWN/UP':
void UpdateWorld(){
    float delta = timeSinceLastCall()
    if(playerIsMoving)
        player.pos += speed * delta;
}
```